# How to Convert IST or UTC time to PST?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to convert the IST(indian standard timing) to UTC and then to  PST(Pacific standard timing).

Can you guys please help me doing it in Jquery.

I will provide the code what i have.

Here i have got the IST timing and am assigning that value to a text input timepicker field. I want this to be converted to UTC time and then from UTC to PST..

```
var dt = new Date();    
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();    
var totime = time.toString();    
$('#reschedule_time').val(totime);
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

There is a lightweight JavaScript date library called moment JS which can do this.The same library was used to implement it. Check out the below jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/edoovyo9/1/

```
var utc = moment.utc(new Date());
alert("UTC: " + utc.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
var pst = moment(utc).zone('-0800'); //-8 hours offset
alert("PST: " + pst.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

Comment: Can we use above code for other formats(like ISO) ?